# In a content security policy header: Should the url's be quoted or not, and is there any security implication to this decision?

Tags: web-browser, content-security-policy

So in a CSP like the below:

`content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com`

Should the url part be quoted like this (example from mozilla security [1]) - even though this example has both styles:

```
# Disable unsafe inline/eval and plugins, only load scripts and stylesheets from same origin, fonts from google,
# and images from same origin and imgur. Sites should aim for policies like this.
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; font-src 'https://fonts.googleapis.com';
             img-src 'self' https://i.imgur.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
```

Or unquoted like this:

```
# Disable unsafe inline/eval, only load resources from same origin except also allow images from imgur
# Also disables the execution of plugins
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://i.imgur.com; object-src 'none'
```

[1] Examples from here: https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/web_security#content-security-policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard clearly defines the syntax. In [section 4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#source-list-syntax) it contains the following:

```
source-list       = *WSP [ source-expression *( 1*WSP source-expression ) *WSP ]
              / *WSP "'none'" *WSP
source-expression = scheme-source / host-source / keyword-source / nonce-source / hash-source
...
host-source       = [ scheme-part "://" ] host-part [ port-part ] [ path-part ]
keyword-source    = "'self'" / "'unsafe-inline'" / "'unsafe-eval'"
```

Based on this URL should not be quoted while keyword sources like 'self', 'unsafe-inline' ... must be quoted. The example you cite where the URL is quoted does not match the standard and is likely wrong.

In fact, when trying to use such a quoted URL Chrome will complain:

> The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'font-src' contains an invalid source: `''https://example.com''`. It will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! What are the implications for quoting it? Will real browsers handle it gracefully or just ignore it?

Comment: @user230910: Chrome will ignore it, see updated answer.